# Using pivot_longer with multiple paired columns in the wide dataset

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
input <- 
  data.frame(
    event = 1:2,
    url_1 = c("g1", "g3"),
    name_1 = c("dc", "nyc"),
    url_2 = c("g2", "g4"),
    name_2 = c("sf", "la"))
```

Essentially there are pairs of indexed columns that are stuck together in wide form. I want to convert to long to give this output:

```
output <- 
  data.frame(
    event = c(1,1,2,2),
    url = c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"),
    name = c("dc", "sf", "nyc", "la"))
```

I want to do this using `pivot_longer`. I've tried this:

```
input %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("_"))
```

How can I get the function to recognize the column-pairs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use `.value` in the `names_to` argument:

```
input %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -event, 
    names_to = c(".value", "item"), 
    names_sep = "_"
  ) %>% 
  select(-item)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  event url   name 
  <int> <fct> <fct>
1     1 g1    dc   
2     1 g2    sf   
3     2 g3    nyc  
4     2 g4    la
```

From [this article on pivoting](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html):

> Note the special name .value: this tells pivot_longer() that that part of the column name specifies the “value” being measured (which will become a variable in the output).