# Using pivot longer to collapse data from multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I've read through a number of similar posts and tutorials but am really struggling to understand the solution to my issue. I have a dataset that is wide, and when I make it longer - I want to collapse two sets of data (both duration and results).

For each participant (`id`), there is a category, and then a series of blood test results. Each test has both duration (in days) and a result (numeric value).

Here's how it looks now:

| id | category | duration_1 | results_1 | duration_2 | results_2 | duration_3 | results_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | diabetic | 58 | 32 | 65 | 56 | 76 | 87 |
| 02 | prediabetic | 54 | 32 | 65 | 25 | 76 | 35 |
| 03 | unknown | 46 | 65 | 65 | 56 | 21 | 67 |

How I'd like it to be is:

| id | category | duration | results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | diabetic | 58 | 32 |
| 01 | diabetic | 65 | 56 |
| 01 | diabetic | 76 | 87 |
| 02 | prediabetic | 54 | 32 |
| 02 | prediabetic | 65 | 25 |
| 02 | prediabetic | 76 | 35 |
| 03 | unknown | 46 | 65 |
| 03 | unknown | 65 | 25 |
| 03 | unknown | 21 | 67 |

I can get pivot longer to work for "results" - but I can't get it to pivot on both "results" and "duration".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm still fairly new to R.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if there is a master duplicate, but there's a few out there, including this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940984/using-pivot-longer-with-multiple-paired-columns-in-the-wide-dataset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/25925556/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28729506/5325862, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47272371/5325862

Answer (score 3):

One way is to separate the column names into two columns while you pivot (hence the `names_sep` below). Then, you can just drop the column number.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!c(id, category),
                      names_to = c(".value", "num"),
                      names_sep = "_") %>%
  dplyr::select(-num)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  id    category    duration results
  <chr> <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
1 01    diabetic          32      23
2 01    diabetic          87      67
3 01    diabetic          98      78
4 02    prediabetic       43      45
5 02    prediabetic       34      65
6 02    prediabetic       12      12
7 03    unknown           32      54
8 03    unknown           75      45
9 03    unknown           43      34
```

Data

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c("01", "02", "03"),
      category = c("diabetic", "prediabetic", "unknown"),
      duration_1 = c(32, 43, 32),
      results_1 = c(23, 45, 54),
      duration_2 = c(87, 34, 75),
      results_2 = c(67, 65, 45),
      duration_3 = c(98, 12, 43),
      results_3 = c(78, 12, 34)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )
```

Comment: why use `dplyr::` etc? Youve already loaded `tidyverse`

Comment: also note `pivot_longer(df, -c(id, category),  names_to = ".value",names_pattern = '([^_]+)')`

Comment: @Onyambu As far as `dplyr::`, I just prefer (in general) to always be explicit. Great, thanks for that suggestion on the names pattern. That's a really clever way to handle it!

Comment: Its okay, though you do not need it once you have loaded the libraries. Thats the whole purpose of loading the library. eg you are not using `magritrr::\`%>%\``

Comment: Thanks that worked well.  Much appreciated!